# Is it possible to sort List Tiles based on date

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of Tasks stored as documents in Firestore, each with a 'DueDate' key. How can I sort this list so that the items with the closest date show at the top? They Won't be in that order in Firestore.

Here's My Current Code

```
 return new ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
              visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -4),
              title: new Text(document.data()['Name']),
              trailing: new Text(DateFormat.MMMd().format((document.data()['DueDate'].toDate()))),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you have two options, when you fetch your data from firebase, you can use `collection('yourCollection').Orderby('DueDate').get()`, which is the cleanest approach. You might get an error saying that an index doesn't exist for this query, and it'll give you a link to follow to create this index in Firebase.
The long thing would be this:

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> myList = snapshot.data.docs.map((e)=> e.data()).toList().sort((a, b) => a['DueDate'].toDate().compareTo(b['DueDate'].toDate()));

 return new ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: myList.map((Map<String,dynamic> document) {
            return new ListTile(
              visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -4),
              title: new Text(document['Name']),
              trailing: new Text(DateFormat.MMMd().format((document['DueDate'].toDate()))),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

Comment: You're most welcome, Jim. Welcome to Stackoverflow.